# IBM Watson Assistant Timeout/ Idle Question

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Hi I am currently making a chatbot that would be integrated to my facebook page. Would like to ask how can I make my chatbot say something like "Our conversation is idle" after the user is stalling or idle. I am currently on the Free Plan

Comment: This is currently not possible as the chatbot is reactive

Answer (score 0):

You would need to bake this into your application. ie. the code between Watson Assistant and Facebook Messanger. The application would deliver a message to Facebook, then start a timer. On expiry it would post your 'idle' message.